# Manipulating OUT parameters from function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions, out-parameters

I have a function that has two OUT parameters. I want to call that function from another function and put those OUT parameters to two variables. Although I saw some similar questions here, I have some troubles with saving those two parameters to two variables.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function_2(OUT out_code2 integer, OUT out_message2 text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   --s_code integer;
   --s_message text;
BEGIN
    --Calling first function, return two out parameters and end function
    SELECT some_function_1() INTO out_code2, out_message2;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function_1(OUT out_code1 integer, OUT out_message1 text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   --s_code integer;
   --s_message text;
BEGIN

   out_code1:= 1;
   out_message1:= 'TEST';

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `some_function_2()` you should use a query which returns two values, not a record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function_2(OUT out_code2 integer, OUT out_message2 text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    --Calling first function, return two out parameters and end function
    SELECT out_code1, out_message1 FROM some_function_1() INTO out_code2, out_message2;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: this was just an example. I have a bigger function that has to return few OUT parameters and will be calles from another function. I want to insert those OUT params into some variable in that other function. That's why I didn't use a query.

Comment: The error what I get when I call some_function_2 is : "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "(1,TEST)""

Comment: Read the answer once more, copy and paste my function, and then test it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it at first. You are right, this is working, didn't know that you can access OUT params from function like this. Thx a lot.

Comment: It's ok. It should be the preferred way to access more then one out parameters.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to ask you also how to call some function that accepts two arrays, one for numbers and the other for text. I tried with SELECT some_function(ARRAY[invoice_list], ARRAY[amount_list]); but it seems that array list wont pass like this.

Comment: To build an array from set of rows you should use `array_agg`. If you do not find a solution ask a new question.